# how to pass a variable from html to node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

so I have this app that reads a file uploaded from the client (index.html)
I want to get the file that was uploaded on html and user it on my app.js to read it.
How do I do that.
Here goes the files bellow:

**index.html**

```
 <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">
 <input type="submit">
```

**app.js**

```
 var fs = require('fs');
 var readMe = fs.readFileSync(??? , 'utf8');
 console.log(readMe);
```

Comment: You'll need an API and submit via a form or some other request.

Answer (score 0):

This should return you the full path of the selected file:

```
var readMe = fs.readFileSync(document.getElementById("myFile").value , 'utf8');
```

Comment: That won't work, node doesn't have access to the document which is browser only.

Comment: Whoops, I was thinking it was all front-end somehow. Was wondering how he had access to fs on the client-side, but I guess that explains it!